# hartl tutorial ParameterMissing in GuidesController#edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

I am following the hartl tutorial to build my app,
but I had not use User as my model but Guide.

now I'm in the chapter 9.2.1
when I link to the edit_path, the wrong is resulted:

> ActionController::ParameterMissing in GuidesController#edit

and the aplication trace is

> app/controllers/guides_controller.rb:42:in `guide_params'
>   app/controllers/guides_controller.rb:29:in`edit'

my guides_controller.rb is

```
class GuidesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :signed_in_guide, only: [:edit, :update, :index]
  before_action :correct_guide,   only: [:edit, :update]

  def index
    @guides = Guide.all
  end

  def new
    @guide = Guide.new
  end
  def show
    @guide = Guide.find(params[:id])
  end
  def create
    @guide = Guide.new(guide_params)
    if @guide.save
        # successful
      guide_sign_in @guide
        flash[:success] = "guide signup success!"
        redirect_to @guide
    else
        flash[:success] = "guide signup failed!"
        render 'new'
    end
  end
  def edit
    @guide = Guide.find(params[:id])
    if @guide.update_attributes(guide_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @guide
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end




  private
      def guide_params
        params.require(:guide).permit(:name, :email,
        :password, :password_confirmation)
      end

    def signed_in_guide
      unless guide_signed_in?
        store_location
        redirect_to guidesignin_url, notice: "Please sign in."
      end
    end

    def correct_guide
      @guide = Guide.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_guide?(@guide)
    end


end
```

I don't understand why the params will missing...
Could anyone help me? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code should looks like:

```
def edit
  @guide = Guide.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  @guide = Guide.find(params[:id])
  if @guide.update_attributes(guide_params)
    flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
    redirect_to @guide
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

And u can remove `@guide = Guide.find(params[:id])` from this methods if u want to use `before_action :correct_guide,   only: [:edit, :update]`